# ASCII encoded unicode to SQL statement in PHP with mb_convert_encoding

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, mb-convert-encoding

I'm working with a file type that is comprised of ASCII characters only. Other characters are encoded. Two byte characters are preceded with `\X2\` and followed by `\X0\` and four byte characters use `\X4\` and `\X0\` . I can find these easily enough but I'm not sure how to then handle them.

e.g. the character `ø` is given as `\X2\00F8\X0\`.

My whole string I'm looking for is `100 mm\X2\00F8\X0\`.

How can I get that to a string that I could then say insert into my DB?

I figure I need to use `mb_convert_encoding()`

But I'm not sure which encoding I want to go to and from.

Any ideas?

Put simply I have "100 mm\X2\00F8\X0\" and I want to output that as "100 mmø"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so all I needed was `hex2bin('00F8')`

Then `utf8_encode(...)` to get it from utf-16 to utf 8

Comment: `utf8_encode` does not convert UTF-16 to UTF-8. Whatever result you think you're getting is either wrong or a coincidence.

Comment: 0x00F8 is the utf-16 representation of ø.
0xC3 0xB8 is it in utf-8.

does utf8_encode not take any encoding and represent that as utf 8? 

if not then it may be a coincidence because its behaving exactly as I expect it to with any characters i've tried

Comment: Read the documentation. It only works with Latin-1. It *can't* magically convert from every possible undefined encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on SQL server you are using. For example for MySQL you can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

This method automatically takes encoding from your sql connection so it is safe to use.

I would pass raw value 100m ø.

Comment: My question is how to get from the encoded value to the raw value.
Btw my db is Postgresql.